# Thread order for kafka consumer group threads differs on every start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using kafka-streams 2.0.1 in Spring Boot 2.1.4 context. The CONSUMER-ID has the following pattern (autogenerated bei kafka-streams!?):

```
<client.id>-StreamThread-<threadSequenceNumber>-<consumer|producer|restore-consumer> (source: StreamsConfig.java)
```

I figured out, that the value: `threadSequenceNumber` is at startup of my application not every time the same, because I have two StreamThread provided by Beans.
I tried already to force the right order with annotating the bean with `@DependsOn`.

Everytime when the `threadSequenceNumber` changes the last offsets are lost.
Anyone an idea how I can force the correct order?

Comment: could you just ommit that value? I mean, can you configure the autogenerated id?

Comment: I hope it is possible. I tried it so set the value with the property: `group.id`, but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct. The thread sequence number is create by Kafka Streams. There is nothing Spring Boot can do about it.

Note, that this behavior will change in upcoming 2.3 release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8285

> Everytime when the threadSequenceNumber changes the last offsets are lost.

Why this? Offsets are committed based on the `application.id`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just a hour ago I got the reason. I was distracted by the Spring Boot Update. The reason was the offset.retention. It occured just randomly in this business case.
And yes. The offsets are committed to the `application.id` and there was never a relation to the threadSequenceNumber.
Sorry about this -.-'